# How I can make "where" -enviroment with text "where" in front of list?

Tags: lists, environments

I want to do *where* enviroment like in the picture? How can I do that?
There should also be *where* text inside the enviroment. I have used that *where* enviroment code below this all over my article so I want to changes it to be like in the picture.

```
\newenvironment{where}[1]%
{\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
        {##1}\hfil}%
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{%
        \labelwidth+\labelsep}}}%
{\end{list}}
```

[image: I want this]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty, using not a list, but a `tabularx`, with some help from the `calc` package. The symbols column is set in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for >{} and <{}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof
\newenvironment{where}{%
where \tabularx{\linewidth-\widthof{where }}[t]{>{$}r<{$} X}%
}{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}
Some text, then
\begin{equation}
a = bcd
\end{equation}
\begin{where}
a & is the \ldots \\
b & is \ldots \\
c & lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur etc.\@ etc.\@ ad infinitum until this text has at least two lines \\
abcd & etc.
\end{where}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have used lists now so for me it could be easier to change the code which is in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A different but perhaps simpler approach, could also be to just utilise `itemize` without bullets but using "where" instead, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\labelitemi{}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[where] $\gamma_F$ is the partial safety factor for \underline{load}
    \item $\gamma_M$ is the partial safety factor for \underline{resistance}
    \item $E_d$ is the design value of the force or moment caused by the load
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can always adjust the itemize to your likings, such as adding a `\hspace{}` after the "where" and choosing the distance you want: `\item[where\hspace{0.4cm}] $gamma_F$ is...` or reduce the vertical spacing by adding `\itemsep0em` right after beginning the itemize environment. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\labelitemi{}
\begin{itemize}
    \itemsep0em
    \item[where \hspace{0.4cm}] $\gamma_F$ is the partial safety factor for \underline{load}
    \item $\gamma_M$ is the partial safety factor for \underline{resistance}
    \item $E_d$ is the design value of the force or moment caused by the load
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]